# extracting data from a weird looking object in R script

Tags: r

In my R script...

I have an object `myObject` which is something that looks like this:

```
> myObject
          m    convInfo        data        call dataClasses     control 
      FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE       FALSE
```

It is what is returned from an `is.na(obj)` where `obj` is an `nls` fit.

I'm trying to test if that first item is FALSE rather than TRUE. How can I extract that out? I tried `myObject$m` but that didn't work.

Comment: sorry forgot to change the title.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail? Maybe `str(t)` and `dput(t)`.  or at least describe how you've created `t`.  Its also worth noting that `t` is a built-in function that you have overwritten which is not the best practice.

Comment: +1 on comment for cautionary note on overwriting base R functions. Totally screws things up in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a named (logical) vector.

```
> v <- 1:5
> names(v) <- LETTERS[1:5]
> is.na(v)
    A     B     C     D     E 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
> myObj <- .Last.value
```

You address it like any other atomic vector:

```
> myObj[1]
    A 
FALSE 
> myObj[1] == FALSE
   A 
TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `nls()` is a list. The behaviour of `is.na()` on a list is somewhat peculiar in the sense of what is an is not `NA`. From `?is.na`:

```
Value:

     The default method for ‘is.na’ applied to an atomic vector returns
     a logical vector of the same length as its argument ‘x’,
     containing ‘TRUE’ for those elements marked ‘NA’ or, for numeric
     or complex vectors, ‘NaN’ (!) and ‘FALSE’ otherwise.  ‘dim’,
     ‘dimnames’ and ‘names’ attributes are preserved.

     The default method also works for lists and pairlists: the result
     for an element is false unless that element is a length-one atomic
     vector and the single element of that vector is regarded as ‘NA’
     or ‘NaN’.
```

So `t` is a logical vector with the `TRUE` & `FALSE` values in your `t` determined as per the quoted text above. Therefore all of

```
t[1]
t["m"]
head(t, 1)
```

extract the first element of `t`. If you want to test for `FALSE` then I might try:

```
!isTRUE(t[1])
```

E.g.

```
> set.seed(1)
> logi <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 5, replace = TRUE)
> logi
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> !isTRUE(logi[1])
[1] FALSE
```

The reason the `$` version won't work is that `$` is documented to apply *only* to non-atomic vectors. `logi` (or your `t`) is an atomic vector, in that it contains elements of the same type.

```
> is.atomic(logi)
[1] TRUE
> names(logi) <- letters[1:5]
> logi$a
Error in logi$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> logi["a"]
   a 
TRUE
```